# PHP mysqli insert date from string

Tags: php, date, mysqli

Im getting sick of all that date stuff.
This is what I try:

```
$string         = '24/10/1985';
$bday           = explode('/', $string);
$insertbday     = $bday[2] . '-' . $bday[1] . '-' . $bday[0];
$insertbday     = date("Y-m-d", $insertbday);
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO user (bday) VALUES ($insertbday)");
```

But ofc there is 0000-00-00 then. How to do this right?

Comment: Why not insert the timestamp and convert it on the php end?

Comment: Why timestamp? Thats birth dates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter of `date` is a timestamp. Use `strtotime()` to convert `$insertbday`.

Change this line:

```
$insertbday = date("Y-m-d", $insertbday);
```

to:

```
$insertbday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($insertbday));
```

*Update*

Also, add single quotes around `$insertbday` to query:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO user (bday) VALUES ('$insertbday')");
```

Comment: What happens? You still get `0000-00-00`?

Comment: Hmmm... what is the field type of `bday`?

Comment: the type is just date, I also use the same to insert current date with NOW() for it

Comment: The single quotes did the trick :D Thanks. Date in PHP is really weird

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
$string         = '24/10/1985';
$bday           = strtotime($string);
$insertbday     = date("Y-m-d", $bday);
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO user (bday) VALUES ($insertbday)");
```

Comment: `strtotime('24/10/1985')` is not valid, and will fail.

Comment: Actually there is no problem with the code. But the problem is with the `24/10/1985` if you change it to `10/24/1985` you will get the desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

`date()` expects a unix timestamp... 
and I think you are passing it a date as a string.

you should try this:

```
$insertbday     = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($insertbday));
```

or apart from a `strtotime()` function you can try it with `Datetime object`

```
$NewBday= new DateTime($insertbday);
$NewBday= date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $NewBday);
```